# Setting file version number in Visual Studio 2005 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++-2005

Can anyone point me in the right direction how to configure Visual Studio 2005 with our C++ console project how we can include a 'File Version' in the details section of the file properties.

I've tried resource files without any luck. This is with a C++ project just for clarification, and big thank you for the guys you responded with C# suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you are talking about unmanaged c++, you need to add a version resource to the project.

right-click on the project, choose add - Resource.... Choose Version and press new.
There you can enter all info you need.

Comment: I do not see "version" resource at right-click on the project, choose add - Resource.

Comment: @RedFox does ["How to: Create a Resource"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fc1e5by.aspx) help? Note that this answer does not apply to C++/CLI projects, and also not to windows store apps written in C++.

Answer (score 7):

You have to have one `VS_VERSION_INFO` section in your resource (*.rc) file(s) that compile into your project.

In the Visual Studio 2005 Solution Explorer, open the context menu on your C++ project and choose Add, Resource.

Mark Version and click "New".

Fill in the fields as desired and save the file.

Build.

Now your project output has a FileInfo resource.

Please be aware that Windows Vista does not show all available version info in the Explorer context menu's "Details" tab.

Answer (score 4):

For c++ projects I use [StampVer](http://blog.dixo.net/downloads/stampver-win32-version-resource-stamping/) and call it as a post build operation including check in/out of revision control for release builds.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason for your file version to be different than the version of the assembly inside, I think it is a better idea to provide the **AssemblyVersion** alone. If you do not specify an **AssemblyFileVersion**, it will automatically get the same value, so you can see your assembly's version directly in the file's properties.

The advantage is that you can use a wildcard and allow the version to be automatically incremented, so that every time you compile the library you get a different build and/or revision number. As far as I can tell, this trick does **not** work with **AssemblyFileVersion**, so you have to increment it by hand.

Of course, all this only applies if you're writing .NET code. Are you by any chance talking about a project using unmanaged code?