# Visual Studio 2008 Generate Manifest from Macros

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, manifest

I have created a C++ application in Visual Studio 2008.  Now I would like to add properties to the manifest such as the application name and version.  Both of these properties are defined within the C++ code as pre-processor macros.  Is there anyway for me to populate the manifest from these MACRO values?  For example:

```
#define APP_NAME    "MyAppName"
#define APP_VERSION "MyAppVersion"
```

Is there some `#pragma` statement that I can use to add this information to the manifest?  Something like:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/MANIFEST:name=" APP_NAME " version=" APP_VERSION)
```

Comment: The syntax is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifestdependency-specify-manifest-dependencies). Implicit concatenation of string literals works fine, like you've shown in the example.

Comment: @CodyGray Perhaps I am missing something, but that link appears to address how to add a dependency to the manifest.  Does it also explain how to add the identity of the application being compiled to the manifest?

Comment: That is the section in which the name goes, as it shows in the example starting with `#pragma`. Note that Microsoft [requires the application name to be in the format "Organization.Division.Name"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191). In the example on the previously linked page, the name is `Test.Research.SampleAssembly`. Or did you mean something different by "identity of the application"? I don't know of any other application name/identity that goes into a manifest file.

Comment: It turns out that this question is unrelated to what I was trying to do, which was to set the property values displayed in a Windows file properties dialog.  That problem [already has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308307/setting-file-version-number-in-visual-studio-2005-c).  I will leave this question open, in case anyone else is looking for a way to do this.

Comment: @CodyGray Again, I appologize if this is due to my own ignorance, but my understanding is that the /MANIFESTDEPENDENCY pragma specifies assemblies upon which this application is dependent, and therefore that name property would be specifying the name of some other assembly (not this one).  I think I am looking for a way to specify a value for the name attribute on the *assemblyIdentity* tag that is a child of the *assembly* tag.  See the example at the bottom of [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191) for an example.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I appears I *was* misunderstanding what you meant by application name. Dependencies are the normal reason why people use manifests, so I guess I was making some incorrect assumptions. I actually have no idea if you can specify an identity on the linker's command line. It doesn't look like it from reading the documentation, but I've never looked into it because no one actually does this. By the way, there *is* a way to create the VERSION resource you want from #defined macros, but the question you found doesn't cover it. The resource compiler (RC) has a limited C-style preprocessor.